# How to use my PC's VPN on Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android-studio, vpn

I have searched everywhere for this question and couldn't find it anywhere.

So I'm working on an app for a project and the authentication only works within the university's internet.

I configured a VPN on my pc and everything works fine but the actual android device emulator doesn't connect to my VPN (although I have connectivity to internet).

I have tried to change proxy settings within android studio but nothing works.

Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator as an alternative of an Android Studio emulator. The Genymotion emulator works correctly even through the VPN.